# Radio button checked status with jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

Here is the basic code

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="r" value="a" id="a" checked="checked" />
  <label for="a">A</label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="r" value="b" id="b" />
  <label for="b">B</label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

So I need to have it work as:

1 Click on the <label> and check if the sibling <radio> is checked="checked" then add "selected" class to the parent <li>

2 Click on the <label> and check if the sibling <radio> is NOT checked then add checked="checked" to the sibling <radio> and add "selected" class to the parent <li> also remove all the other "checked" and "selected" in the <ul>

Could you help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on the label should check the radio buttons automatically in the browser. So, you just need do add a click event to the label/input that will set the class on the li's.

Something like this should work:
**HTML** (I just added `id="mylist"`)

```
<ul id="mylist">
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="r" value="a" id="a" checked="checked" />
  <label for="a">A</label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="r" value="b" id="b" />
  <label for="b">B</label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
 $("#mylist input, #mylist label").click(function() {
  $("#mylist li").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using `label` with the `for` attribute there should really be no need to attach an event to the `label` element, unless you need to contend with IE6 making you're life difficult.

```
$(':radio[name="r"]').change(function(){
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
}).filter(':checked').change();
```

Documentation for: [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

**See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/mzPk9/**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this isn't the most elegant way but with a change to your markup (adding class 'a' and 'b' to your li - basically the same value as the id of the radio elem. contained) here we go:

```
$('label').click(function(){
    // if the radio is already checked
    if ($('#'+$(this).attr('for')).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
        $('ul li').removeClass('selected');  // remove previous selected items
        $('.'+$(this).attr('for')).addClass('selected'); // add new selected item
    } else {
        // radio not checked
        $('#'+$(this).attr('for')).attr('checked','checked'); // check radio (altough this should be automatic, without js
        $('ul li').removeClass('selected'); // clear previous selected items
        $('.'+$(this).attr('for')).addClass('selected'); // add new selected item
    }
});
```

For speed, I would suggest adding an id to the ul, say "list" and have the code change from

```
$('label').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('#list label').click(function(){
```

Also, from:

```
$('ul li').removeClass('selected');  // remove previous selected items
```

to

```
$('#list li').removeClass('selected');  // remove previous selected items
```

Good luck!